# Prove or disprove that there is an abelian, noncyclic group of order 52.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups, sylow-theory

So I've heard one must invoke Sylow's theorems in order to break down something like this. So far I know that there is a subgroup of order 13 in G, and that it's the only subgroup of order 13 in G. To go from there to proving that it's abelian or cyclic or not seems trickier. Helpful hints appreciated, thank you.

Comment: There is no need of Sylow theorems.

Comment: What abelian non-cyclic groups can you think of?

Comment: Klein-four group all that comes to mind.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Consider a direct product of cyclic groups whose orders multiply to $52$, but such that the product is not cyclic. The fact that

$$52 = 2^2 \cdot 13$$

is highly relevant here.

Comment: So Z_2 x Z_2 x Z_13 would be noncyclic yet abelian?

Comment: @Mik Yes, that's a non-cyclic group.

Comment: How do I show that that's non-cyclic though?

Comment: @Mik Show that it doesn't contain an element of order $4$.

Comment: @T.Bongers: Did you mean "it doesn't contain an element of order 52." instead?

Comment: @Prism - either one would do. If it contained an element $x$ of order 52, it would contain an element $x^{13}$ of order 4.

Comment: I'm deepy confused as to how to prove that it doesn't have an element of order 4 or 52 without listing out every element.

Comment: All elements in $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{13}$ are killed by $26$, so everything has order dividing 26.

Comment: Or, $(4x, 4y, 4z) = 0$ implies $4z = 0$ in $\mathbb Z/13$, and thus we must have $z=0$ ($4$ is invertible), now observe that there is no element of order 4 in $\mathbb Z/2 \oplus \mathbb Z/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Forget Sylow theorem. Note $52=2.26$ and consider $$\mathbb Z_2\oplus\mathbb Z_{26}$$

Of course this one is abelian (the components being so). Is it possible to find $(a,b)\in\mathbb Z_2\oplus\mathbb Z_{26}$ such that $l.c.m.\{|a|,|b|\}=52?$

Answer (score 0):

Let G be any group of order 52. Then by sylow theorem it has only one sylow 13 subgroup and hence is normal in G, let it be H. Then G/H forms a quotient group of order 5, which implies G/H is cyclic and hence G is abelian.